# Search box on area51 does nothing when I enter text and hit enter

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, search

I saw the different problems in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54423/proposal-search-box-doesnt-work-on-area51), but what I see is worse:

Repro:

1. log into [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=search) with Chrome 5.0.375.99 beta on Windows 7
2. type "television shows" in the proposal search box
3. hit enter

Expect:

- Some results show up while I type ... and/or
- Results show up after hitting enter

Observed:

- Nothing happens while typing or after hitting enter

Comment: Totally broken in XP + FF 3.6.6.

Comment: Does not work on Opera 10 either.

Comment: FF3.6.6 (hardy heron) too

Comment: FireFox on Win7 repro, check.

Comment: Nothing on FF or chrome (Ubuntu) either

Comment: Doesn't work with Chrome (Win7) either

Comment: Repro'd on FF, Chrome, IE on Win7. Is there a workaround? Eg. A query string I can enter in the address bar?

Comment: Repro on IE7, Vista. There's an "Error on page" dialog also that says `Line: 2 Char: 9372 Error: Object expected`.

Comment: Checking back with IE8 on XP, I see the same error that mmyers reports. A manual workaround, by the way, is enter `http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=` into your URL, and then add your search term to the end. It only works once, though, because the redirect you end up on won't have the same URL. But try it with, say, http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=television+shows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was caused by a typo in our JavaScript. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible Workaround:**

Click `Create a New Proposal` , and in the `Choose a Topic`, enter your query. Start typing in the `Who is this site for` box while your search results are loaded. (Do not click next, do not actually create the proposal).

It doesn't seem to respond well to more complicated queries with + and [ ] etc, but it is a simple search workaround.