# Search on Area51 appears to be not working at the moment

Tags: bug, area-51, search, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search box on area51 does nothing when I enter text and hit enter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57474/search-box-on-area51-does-nothing-when-i-enter-text-and-hit-enter)

I'm trying to search 'Role Playing Games' but nothing is happening.

This error appears to happen for a few other people.  I'm using Chrome.

I checked in IE I'm getting an error

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Sun, 18 Jul 2010 17:14:09 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 1
Char: 9372
Code: 0
URI: http://area51.stackexchange.com/content/js/master.js?v=3526fde3e01e
```

Comment: Please post the error details as an answer in the [original question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57474/search-box-on-area51-does-nothing-when-i-enter-text-and-hit-enter). Thanks!