# Search for diamond (♦) symbol doesn't work

Tags: feature-request, search, moderators, unicode, symbols

Just tried to search for the diamond symbol (♦) and got [no results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%99%A6).

It seems that searching for any single symbol is not implemented. For instance:

[Search for point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=.)
[Search for comma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2C)

Even more, searching for the [...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=...) doesn't work too. However since diamond symbol (♦) for whole Stack Exchange has special meaning it would be desired to allow searching for that symbol.

Comment: An **old** seemingly *unrelated* answer: which [explains that there's a **3** character minimum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54479/282094), that probably still applies, but ***that*** Q&A is a record-worst suggestion for a duplicate (even if it's correct). Implementing a search for fewer than 3 characters may not be approved, however useful it might be (due to the explosion of matches that would be applied). Pretty sure there a *better* duplicate request somewhere ... --- See also: [Wildcards must be 4 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16615/282094).

Answer (score -5):

The diamond symbol represents a moderator, so I think that it should be in the “Filter” list and not the search area. For symbols, like comma and ... they should also be included in the filter list. So, when you click on the diamond symbol in the filter list, you will only be able to find moderators.